# Material Design transitions

Tags: android, android-animation, compatibility, android-5.0-lollipop, material-design

how you can do this kind of transitions ?

[Transitions Consistent Choreography](https://material-design.storage.googleapis.com/videos/meaningfultransitions-consistentchoreography_do1_large_xhdpi.webm)

The idea is to load a listview and transitioning as it does Google Play Kiosco

[Google Play Kiosco](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.magazines&hl=es)

Comment: That looks rather much of an AnimationSet animating multiple views at the same time. Only circular reveal seems to be L -related. I might be mistaken though.